# ffmpeg + libavfilter's drawtext doesn't print accented characters

Tags: ffmpeg, diacritics, drawtext

FFMpeg's libavfilter drawtext filter doesn't seem to want to print accented characters like é, and just leaves a space where they should be. This happens both when loading the text from file and when specifying it from the command line:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mpg -vf drawtext=text:"Café doesn\\\\\'t print the é" ...
ffmpeg -i test.mpg -vf drawtext=textfile:file_with_accents_inside.txt ...
```

Is there any way to make ffmpeg draw the accented characters correctly? I've tried a couple of different fonts to make sure they weren't the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Using an ffmpeg build from 03-25-12 compiled for Windows, I was able to get the drawtext filter to print the é using the Arial font.  Although to do it, I had to use Windows CL, instead of MinGW.  MinGW wouldn't even print the é in the command line.  I can't test a Linux command line right now, but that might be your problem.  What command line/ffmpeg version are you using?

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your response. I'm on Debian at the moment, using:
ffmpeg version git-2012-05-15-b977779, built on May 15 2012 13:03:08 with gcc 4.4.5